# Which package manages the Ctrl+F function?

Tags: search, find

I'm trying to find out which package manages the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Find) function. I need this so I can properly file a bug; the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> function is constantly being launched on whatever application I have on top, and it's really annoying. I've ruled out hardware issues, and just need to find which packaged ctrl+f belongs to so I can file the correct information.

I've tried searching with [`apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html); combing through [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto); and searching [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) and [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/), but the search terms `Ctrl+f` and `find` are just too general. If someone knows which package I need to report, or would know where to search, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Ctrl+F functionality is present in multiple packages. It is not always provided by the same package. Can you be more specific about the problem you're trying to figure out how to report as a bug?

Comment: Sure. here's what's in the bug as well (bug #1010033): Recently, the ctrl+f function is randomly and repeatedly launching on whatever application I have on top. This isn't application-specific; it's been observed on Chromium, Firefox, Nautilus, gPodder, Liferea, and LibreOffice (off the top of my head). It's _as if_ I've hit ctrl+f to search for something through the application, but I'm not touching anything, and it's getting in the way of using the application. When I close the function, it just pops up again.

Comment: It also happens in both Unity and Gnome Shell, so it doesn't seem environment-particular. And I've ruled out hardware issues; this is happening on a laptop, and I've used it for a few hours with the keyboard removed, and it still occurs. That makes me think it must be software-related, and it must be something more at the system-level if it's happening in a variety of applications.

Comment: I've isolated something: This seems to happen after coming out of a blank screen. In fact it immediately happens on whatever application is up front as soon as I reactivate the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the bug no matter which application you opened, I suggest reporting the bug in the [unity package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity).

And yes, [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) is a good place to search for Ubuntu packages.  You can also check out the [Bazaar Branches for Ubuntu](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu), there is gold hidden in there.

Comment: Thanks Emerson, but one question: If the problem happens in both Unity and Gnome Shell, wouldn't it be rejected as a Unity issue?